# Spring WebFlux - org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /booking

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, pom.xml

I'm using `WebFlux` router for mapping a `GET` router:

```
@Configuration
public class BookingRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(BookingHandler handler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(GET("/booking"), handler::getBooking);
    }

}
```

Here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>booking.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>booking-parent</artifactId> // contains all spring dependencies, and cannot be modified.
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I try to access `http://localhost:8080/booking`, I get an error in console:

```
{"timestamp":"2023-02-10 21:19:20.709","level":"WARN","thread":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","mdc":{"traceId":"c38258dc765969e9","spanId":"c38258dc765969e9","correlationId":null},"logger":"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver","message":"Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /booking]"}
```

I cannot add an exclusion like below since I cannot modify parent pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: your app is configured with spring mvc, not with webflux. This is the defualt behaviour when you have both spring mvc and spring webflux in your classpath. So you should somehow exclude web mvc dependency

Comment: what kerbermeister is writing is correct, you can try to enforce reactive by setting `SpringApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE)` in the main function as noted in the last section here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.reactive.webflux in the docs